# how to select 2 tables in sql but no repeating?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union-all

I just would like to select bothe tables where table1.id=1
I have 2 tables
table1 : cars.
Table 2 : owner
the table 1 does not have all information
so i would like to get all info in one column. i mean i need the owner-phone

i do like that but i get all column. how to add the id ?

```
drop table cars;
drop table owners;
CREATE TABLE cars(id INTEGER(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, model TEXT,          price TEXT, name TEXT);
create table owners(
id INTEGER(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
phone varchar(25),
name varchar(25),
constraint owners_fk foreign key(id) references carss(id)
);

insert into cars(model , price, name )values('bmw', '10.000', 'thomas');
insert into cars(model , price, name )values('fiat', '5.000', 'none');
insert into owners(phone , name)values( '0333333','thomas');
insert into owners(phone , name)values('04444444','Tom');


SELECT * FROM cars
LEFT JOIN owners ON cars.name = owners.name
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cars
RIGHT JOIN owners ON cars.name = owners.name;
```

the 2 tables will be selected but how can I select only one column of the full union to get all infos in one column ?
I use mysql.

with left join is ok but i do not double names :
[show picture of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lWBQ.jpg)

if i just use left join :

```
SELECT * FROM cars
LEFT JOIN owners ON cars.name = owners.name where name='thomas';
```

Comment: remove the `ALL`? `UNION` removes duplicates.

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @GurV I use mysql

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using MySQL, which doesn't support `full outer join`.  The correct way to do this is to compile a list of all the names and then use `left join`:

```
select n.name, o.id, o.phone, c.model, c.price
from (select name from owners union select name from cars) n left join
     owners o
     on o.name = n.name left join
     cars c
     on c.name = n.name;
```

Comment: hi @Gordon Linoff, but if I have many names, i will need more time to type all like your code !!!

Comment: now i get a bit good result with :
'' SELECT * FROM cars
LEFT JOIN owners ON cars.name = owners.name where name='thomas';  but the names (fields) should not be repeated the fields double '

Comment: @Json . . . Just list the columns you want in the `SELECT`.